# Giving translators a hint in Chameleon page templates (cpt)

Tags: internationalization, chameleon

I use Chameleon Page templates as my templating language and I'd like to give my translators a hint. (In this case because the word "you" can be translated quite differently depending on the context.)

I cannot find a technique for it in the [documentation](https://chameleon.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference.html#translation-i18n).

How do I do that? Is it even possible?

I *could* abuse i18n:target but I'd rather not.

The resulting piece of the .po file would look like this:

I'd prefer a solution that produces something like this, which I believe to be the standard gettext way of supplying hints to translators.

```
#. i18n: Translate this very formally.
msgid "you"
msgstr ""
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found quite an ugly solution which depends on your translators being somewhat alert.

```
<tal:block i18n:translate="">
  <tal:block
      i18n:name="This is not a dynamic element, this is a hint for translators: translate this very formally"
    >you</tal:block>
</tal:block>
```

This will end up in the .po file as follows:

```
msgid ""
"${This is not a dynamic element, this is a hint for translators: translate this very formally}you"
msgstr ""
```